# Update entity type in TypeORM single table inheritance

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm, single-table-inheritance

Lets say I have a `Base` entity that implements [typeorm `TableInheritance`](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entity-inheritance) (single table inheritance),
and I have two deriving entities: `A` and `B`.

I want to be able to change the entity type of `A` to `B`. something like this:

```
const a = em.findOne(A, {}) // found one entity - entityType column is now 'A'
em.save(a as B)
em.findOne(A, {}) // nothing is found
em.findOne(B, {}) // found one entity - entityType column is now 'B'
```

The uid is the same and typeorm won't let me simply insert \ update.

Anyone know a way to do this? My current solution is deleting and resaving but that might be problematic with cascading relations.

Answer (score 2):

Convert entity with `uid` from `A` to `B`:

```
await em.update(A, { uid: uid }, {[entityTypeColumnName]: 'B'})
```